# geb/selenium test, chosen multiple selection

Tags: jquery, select, selenium

I want to test a multiple selection realized via a jquery plugin called chosen.

The HTML of the selection:

```
<select id="pickUsers" name="users" multiple="true" class="many-to-many" >
<option value="1" >me</option>
<option value="3" >leader</option>
<option value="2" >test</option>
</select>
```

Exception is:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

I think it has something todo with a `display: none` css property and read already alot about it but didnt find a solution for exactly my problem

EDIT:

My Selenium bindings are:

```
users {$("select", name:"users")}
```

I tried with that several assignments:

```
users = ["me", "test"] or 

users = [1,2,3]

users = ["1","2","3"]
```

Comment: Which selenium language bindings are you using?

Comment: I updated my question with the bindings

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue. Geb can access only the elements that are visible.
In this case, chosen adds a *display none* to the select (`<select ... style="display:none">`). Therefore you cannot access it using the `$('')` selector.

One workaround is:

In your test:

1. remove the style attribute.
   `js.exec("document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].removeAttribute('style')")`

   This is the only way i could think of since Geb has only [getAttribute](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) for the `$('')` selectors, but does not have a setAttribute.
2. set new select value value
   `$('select').value(1)`

**Note**: It's not an elegant solution since you'll get 2 selects. First that you "unhide", and the second is the one created and styled by chosen. Nevertheless this way you can access the select, set the value an move on with your testing.